# git push --tags trying to push ignored subdirectory

Tags: git, git-submodules

After upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04.1, `git push --tags` is now trying to push ignored subdirectories.

Directory structure has evolved into:

```
top/.git
    subdir1/.git
    subdir2/.git
```

with `.gitignore` of:

```
subdir1/**
subdir2/**
```

Currently running git 2.7.4 (I believe I was running git 2.5.0 before)

Pushing to the master repo works something like this:

```
pushd subdir1; git push --tags; popd
pushd subdir2; git push --tags; popd
echo "Now pushing top"
git push --tags
```

Prior to the upgrade, the above push instructions worked fine.  After the upgrade, the process now does something like this:

```
Now pushing subdir1
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 312 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

Now pushing subdir2
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 312 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

Now pushing top
Pushing submodule 'subdir1'
Pushing submodule 'subdir2'
Pushing submodule 'subdir1'
Pushing submodule 'subdir2'
Pushing submodule 'subdir1'
Pushing submodule 'subdir2'
The following submodule paths contain changes that can
not be found on any remote:
    subdir1
    subdir2
```

After extensive googling, I did try this:

```
git clean -d -i
```

and found subdir1 and subdir2 in the list.  Running `git clean -d -f` removed those directories.

However, this didn't solve the root problem.  Any suggestions as to what to try next?

For reference:

1. `.gitmodules` is empty
2. These directories *used* to be submodules, but they were migrated to separate repos months ago
3. There is no reference to subdir1/2 in .git/config
4. `.git/modules` doesn't exist
5. `git ls-files` doesn't show subdir1 or subdir2 in the list

What can I try next?

Comment: Just for testing: `cd top; git rm --cached subdir1` (no trailing slash), add commit  and push top.

Comment: @VonC No luck -- still looped thru all the subdirectories